# Layout change when change from web to mobile

Tags: html, css, angular, layout, grid

how can I do this layout happen in angular? I don't want to add bootstrap.
Image one is when viewing the page in web browser on laptop and image two is when viewing using a phone.

[image: image one]

[image: image two]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <body>
        <div class="bigDiv">
            <div class="form"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* desktop */
.bigDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
/* mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .bigDiv {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```